# How to reset unused Wordpress slug

Tags: php, wordpress, url, path, slug

I use "virtual pages" in Wordpress (you can google it) and i want to use some page slug that have been used before for a real page, for example:
"domain.com/test".

If i use "domain.com/test1" for example it will work great but if i use "domain.com/test" it will give me 404. i am not sure why but i know it happens only with slugs that was used for real pages before, although they are deleted permanently.

How can i make Wordpress "forget" there was such a page and let me use the slug?

Answer (score 0):

This plugin helps manage redirects.

Maybe give it a try and see if it gives you a better explanation of where those redirects that you want to remove are coming from.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: Not sure what you meant, i don't have any redirects. i get 404 when using old post's slug.